# Symbolic product of two complex numbers

Tags: complex

In Mathematica 11, if I define

```
Subscript[z, 1] = a + I b;
Subscript[z, 2] = c + I d;
```

and compute

```
Subscript[z, 1] Subscript[z, 2] // ComplexExpand
```

I obtain in the TraditionalForm

```
I (a d + b c) + a c - b d
```

Is it possible to obtain instead

a c - b d + I (a d + b c)

written in this order?

Comment: Can you specify the output referring to "usual `(Re + I Im)`"? And what do you mean by "function notation"? I see no function in `I (a d+b c)+a c-b d`

Comment: I'd like to obtain ac-bd+I(ad+bc)

Comment: Is that not exactly what you get?  In it current state, this question is at risk of being closed as unclear.  Please *edit the question*, show what you get (precisely), show what you want instead, and point out the difference in a description.

Comment: I obtain I (ad + bc) + ac-bd instead of ac-bd+I(ad+bc)

Comment: Looks like  you are using `TraditionalForm` somewhere?

Comment: yes by default I use TraditionalForm

Comment: I suspect OP's "function notation" means $I(ad+bc)$

Comment: `Evaluate[Subscript[z, 1] Subscript[z, 2] // ComplexExpand] // 
  HoldForm // TraditionalForm` is this what you want?

Comment: This is silly. I want to answer this question, but can't. Just because 5 people found the question unclear, the "Answer" button should not disappear for everyone.

Comment: @Kagaratsch I think this is not the point. OP said he is using `TraditionalForm`. With `StandardForm`, even OP's code produces `a c - b d + I (b c + a d)`

Comment: @Kagaratsch Next time please just **flag** the post if you have an answer for a closed question.  I reopened the question.  You should now post your answer as an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for the hint! This was the first time that happened to me. I'll know better next time.

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution is

```
Re[Subscript[z, 1] Subscript[z, 2]] + I Im[Subscript[z, 1] Subscript[z, 2]] // ComplexExpand
```

> a c - b d + I (b c + a d)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are concerned with just the order in which Mathematica prints the terms in the output. You should know that Mathematica uses lexicographical order by default. It is however not completely clear what weight the imaginary unit `I` is assigned. Still, the easiest thing is to try different naming conventions and see if the desired result is produced. If we define, i.e.:

```
Subscript[z, 1] = zr[1] + I zi[1];
Subscript[z, 2] = zr[2] + I zi[2];
```

then my Mathematica 11.1 returns

```
Subscript[z, 1] Subscript[z, 2] // ComplexExpand
```

> `-zi[1] zi[2] + zr[1] zr[2] + I (zi[2] zr[1] + zi[1] zr[2])`

which puts the real part before the imaginary part. If I understood your question correctly, this is what you want. If you would prefer different ordering within the real part and imaginary part too, you can play around with other variable naming conventions, until it looks the way you like it.